# Spyder kernel hangs on running scripts that used to work

Tags: python, spyder

Noticed this problem earlier this week: when I try running anything in Spyder, the script will usually execute fine the first time I run it, but if I try to run it again, the kernel hangs indefinitely after printing the standard "runfile('C:/Users..." statement. Ctrl-c doesn't work as an interrupt; the only fix I've found is to restart the kernel, then run some simple command such as a variable declaration (e.g. trying to run the script, restarting the kernel, then immediately retrying the script causes the restarted kernel to hang, but trying to run the script, restarting the kernel, running a simple command like x = 1, THEN retrying the script works - once). It seems like it might be an issue with my local directory, because anything in Spyder's default temp script runs fine. If I save the same script to a local directory, though, the problem persists, even for a one-line print("hello world") program. The problem is occurring with scripts that ran fine as of a week ago, and as far as I know I haven't updated Spyder or Windows in the interim. Has anybody run into anything like this before?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Did you change your graphics backend in `Preferences > IPython console > Graphics`?

Comment: I actually independently stumbled across this fix, and yes, the problem turned out to be the graphics backend. Setting it back to inline resolved it, though it has made life frustrating when I need the externally rendered plots. Is there any fix that you know of?

Comment: Ok, this should be fixed in our latest version (5.2.0), released a couple of weeks ago. I think it's not available in Anaconda yet, so you could try it with our [Windows installer](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases). Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I'm running into this exact problem again on 5.4.5 (py: 3.11.4 qt: 5.12.2 PyQt5: 5.15.9 Windows 10)

Answer (score 2):

Go into the IPython part of spyder's preferences.

In the graphics tab, change the backend to "inline".

This solved this for my colleague on windows (who had this problem since he had set this to "automatic" last week, IPython 8.2.0), thanks @source4mini for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall your Antivirus or Use Anaconda Spyder without Antivirus. Your problem will be solved.