# Spyder 5.1.5 kernel hangs and 5.2.1 won't work with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I had the same issue with kernel hanging on valid scripts:
[spyder kernel hangs...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70221867/spyder-kernal-hangs-on-running-scripts-that-used-to-work)

Spyder 5.2 isn't available yet in Anaconda, but I installed it via the link provided in the answer above.  When I attempt to get it to use my current conda environment, I get the following error:

> *Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.2.0 and < 2.3.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.*

> *You can install it by running in a system terminal:  conda install spyder‑kernels=2.2*

I can't update conda from sypder-kernel=2.1.3 to 2.2.0 due to numerous conflicts.

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I might get Spyder 5.2 working with Anaconda, or do I simply have to wait for it to be released by Anaconda?  I'm not that savvy in this type of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @merv, I added a summary question clarifying what I'm looking for.  I'll look into Conda Forge.

Comment: BTW, the 2.2.0 is now on `anaconda` channel.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please use the Inline backend if the problem persists after installing `spyder-kernels` 2.2.0 in your environments. More fixes about this problem (specifically with respect to the Tkinter backend) will be available in our next version (5.2.2), to be available next week.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. When I try updating spyder-kernels from 2.1.3 to 2.2.0 using anaconda, I get many, many conflicts. I guess will stick with the inline plotting inspyder 5.1.5 until spyder>=5.2 is available via the anaconda channel.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with spyder 5.2.1, I opened `cmd` and typed:

```
pip install spyder-kernels==2.2.0
```

Then it downloaded the right kernel and after opening spyder I didn't get any error related to its kernel version.

Comment: That could break your conda environments very badly on Windows, so it's really not recommended.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that via conda.  When I try updating spyder-channels from 2.1.3 to 2.2.0 using conda, I get many, many conflicts.